# ClassCastException when returning LazySeq from Clojure to Java

Tags: java, clojure, interop, classcastexception, gen-class

I have Clojure function that returns a LazySeq.  When I run this function from the REPL, it works just fine.  However, if I try to call the same function from Java code like this:

```
Object result = com.acme.forecast.core.runforecast("file1.csv", "file2.txt");
```

I get the following exception:

```
Exception in thread "AWT-EventQueue-0" java.lang.ClassCastException: 
  clojure.lang.LazySeq cannot be cast to java.lang.Number
    at com.acme.forecast.core.runforecast(Unknown Source)
    at com.acme.forecast.client.gui.ClientGUI.actionPerformed(ClientGUI.java:180)
```

My gen-class says I'm returning a LazySeq, not a Number:

```
  (:gen-class
    :name com.acme.forecast.core
    :methods [#^{:static true} [runforecast [String String] clojure.lang.LazySeq]])
```

What is going wrong here?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The error does say you're returning LazySeq.  The problem is that it's trying to get stored in a Number, though I can't see where in this code segment.

Answer (score 1):

Never mind.  I found the problem.  There was an old version of the .class file lying around.